# MVC IgnoreRoute to ignore requests coming to a specific folder

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

My site is under the bombardment of some image requests for images that don't exist on my server. Seem to be porn related images that got nothing to do with my site.

Pattern is like this;

/loc208/th_e82_shower028.jpg

/loc171/th_251_shower014.jpg

/loc295/th_21e_shower052.jpg

so they all look under /loc* folder

Is there a way I write a script on my global.asax.cs file of my MVC application that would make the app ignore all these requests so that I don't flood my logs with "The controller for path '/loc295/th_21e_shower052.jpg' could not be found or it does not implement IController" message?

Comment: You've already asked this today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725350/getting-hundreds-of-image-requests-to-the-site-closed

Comment: This is about implementing a route handling strategy for mvc application deal with the problem. My initial question was a broad question which currently reside under server fault for server administration related approaches to the problem.

Comment: This kind of problems is best handled at firewalls/routers at a lower level in the TCP stack rather than waiting it to come to IIS when it's already too late. That's why it was suggested that you ask your question at serverfault.com where you might get more appropriate answers to this particular problem.

Comment: I totally agree with Darin, would also be nice if you provided user-agent and ip for the request.

Comment: OK your point is well received. Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing is the wrong solution here. By the time the request hits ASP.NET, it's already loading your server. You should configure the web server itself -- or, better still, an upstream security appliance -- to reject these.

One way to configure IIS would be to do an [exclude on the folders in question](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/07/overriding-iis6-wildcard-maps-on-individual-directories/). The request would no longer go to ASP.NET and would then 404. But like I said, it's better to do this upstream.